# Where is docker-compose callable file located

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im using Ubuntu 18.04 and docker-compose v1.8. I want to create a service to run docker compose on startup like this

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Compose Application Service
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=PATH_TO_PROJECT
ExecStart=FULL_PATH_TO_DC/docker-compose up
ExecStop=FULL_PATH_TO_DC/docker-compose down
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitIntervalSec=60
StartLimitBurst=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But i cant find out where is `docker-compose` executable to set `FULL_PATH_TO_DC`

I have checked /usr/local/bin - it is not there. I think that documentation that says

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

have been changed since that time I have installed docker-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation regarding [installing docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose) gives a pretty much straightforward answer:

```
$ sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

From this you might deduct, that the executable is located in `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Also, `whereis` might help you...

```
$ whereis docker-compose
```

Comment: About this `sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` - i think when i have installed docker compose some time ago this path was different

Comment: If the answer helped, mark it as the correct one please. And do so with other answers to your other questions. Regarding your second comment - I just looked in the docs and quoted the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You'll most probably find it in `/usr/bin`, if not, then maybe in `/usr/local/bin`

```
$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep compose
docker-compose
```